# SQL Group By depending on case statement?

Tags: sql, database

When you are using a date range in SQL, you also need to Group it. In this case, I am grouping by weeks, but if the value is `less than 10` I want it combined in a single `'Others'` row.

How can I group this by week then by `'Others'` in the week? I only need one `'Others'` row, totaled of all less than `10`.

[image]

```
SELECT SUM(DISTINCT SOTRAN.ACTQTY) AS value
   ,CASE 
        WHEN SUM(DISTINCT SOTRAN.ACTQTY) > 10
    THEN 
     'Week of ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), dateadd(wk, datediff(wk, 0, SOTRAN.tdate), 0), 1)
   ELSE 'Others'
   END AS label
FROM SOTRAN AS SOTRAN
WHERE (
        SOTRAN.tdate >= '1/1/2015 12:00:00 AM'
        AND SOTRAN.tdate <= '12/31/2015 11:59:59 PM'
        )
GROUP BY 
'Week of ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), dateadd(wk, datediff(wk, 0, SOTRAN.tdate), 0), 1)
```

Comment: Have you considered using sqlfiddle? It would help us debug your issue

Answer (score 0):

```
select SUM(distinct SOTRAN.ACTQTY) AS value, 
case  when SUM(distinct SOTRAN.ACTQTY) > 10 then 'Week of ' +  CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),dateadd(wk, datediff(wk, 0, SOTRAN.tdate), 0),1) else 'Others' end AS label
from SOTRAN AS SOTRAN
WHERE ( SOTRAN.tdate>='1/1/2015 12:00:00 AM' AND SOTRAN.tdate<='12/31/2015 11:59:59 PM' )  
GROUP BY 'Week of ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),dateadd(wk, datediff(wk, 0, SOTRAN.tdate), 0),1),label
```

Comment: Just add label in Group By

Comment: makes sense :) Good catch

Comment: 'label' is an invalid column name.

Answer (score 0):

Your entire case statement should be in the group by clause (minus the "AS label").

I've not shared a sqlfiddle before so i hope this works but check this out here:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/fabb86/6

Otherwise just try this:

```
select SUM(distinct SOTRAN.ACTQTY) AS value, 
       case when SUM(distinct SOTRAN.ACTQTY) > 10 then 
         'Week of ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),dateadd(wk, datediff(wk, 0, SOTRAN.tdate), 0),1) else 
          'Others' end AS label
  from SOTRAN AS SOTRAN
 WHERE (SOTRAN.tdate>='1/1/2015 12:00:00 AM' 
   AND SOTRAN.tdate<='12/31/2015 11:59:59 PM' )  
 GROUP BY case when SUM(distinct SOTRAN.ACTQTY) > 10 then 
         'Week of ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),dateadd(wk, datediff(wk, 0, SOTRAN.tdate), 0),1) else 
          'Others' end
```

UPDATE:

```
select SUM(SOTRAN.ACTQTY) AS value, 
       case when SOTRAN.ACTQTY > 10 then 
         'Week of ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),dateadd(wk, datediff(wk, 0, SOTRAN.tdate), 0),1) else 
          'Others' end AS label
  from SOTRAN AS SOTRAN
 WHERE (SOTRAN.tdate>='1/1/2015 12:00:00 AM' 
   AND SOTRAN.tdate<='12/31/2015 11:59:59 PM' )  
 GROUP BY case when SOTRAN.ACTQTY > 10 then 
         'Week of ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),dateadd(wk, datediff(wk, 0, SOTRAN.tdate), 0),1) else 
          'Others' end;
```

Comment: Cannot use an aggregate or a subquery in an expression used for the group by list of a GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Take the sum out of the case statement, and also drop the distinct as they are doing nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You can just write the `Outer Select` to get what you want

```
SELECT SUM(Value),label
FROM
    (
       SELECT SUM(DISTINCT SOTRAN.ACTQTY) AS value
           ,CASE 
             WHEN SUM(DISTINCT SOTRAN.ACTQTY) > 10
                   THEN  'Week of ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), dateadd(wk, datediff(wk, 0, SOTRAN.tdate), 0), 1)
             ELSE 'Others'
            END AS label
       FROM SOTRAN AS SOTRAN
       WHERE (
               SOTRAN.tdate >= '1/1/2015 12:00:00 AM'
               AND SOTRAN.tdate <= '12/31/2015 11:59:59 PM'
            )
       GROUP BY 
             'Week of ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), dateadd(wk, datediff(wk, 0, SOTRAN.tdate), 0), 1)
    ) as innerData
 GROUP BY label
```

OR You can use the `CTE` as below,

```
;WITH innerData AS
(
    SELECT SUM(DISTINCT SOTRAN.ACTQTY) AS value
           ,CASE 
             WHEN SUM(DISTINCT SOTRAN.ACTQTY) > 10
                   THEN  'Week of ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), dateadd(wk, datediff(wk, 0, SOTRAN.tdate), 0), 1)
             ELSE 'Others'
            END AS label
       FROM SOTRAN AS SOTRAN
       WHERE (
               SOTRAN.tdate >= '1/1/2015 12:00:00 AM'
               AND SOTRAN.tdate <= '12/31/2015 11:59:59 PM'
            )
       GROUP BY 
             'Week of ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), dateadd(wk, datediff(wk, 0, SOTRAN.tdate), 0), 1)
)
```

Then just use the select with `groupby`

```
 SELECT SUM(Value),label
 FROM  innerData
 GROUP BY label
```